# How to display the remainder when dividing in emu8086?

Tags: assembly

this is is my proceedure. I am having trouble in how to display the remainder together with the answer. I could display the answer without the remainder properly, but the remainder does not show. can you please help me?

```
.model small
.data 

temp db ?
choice db ?

Input1  dw 5 dup ('$')
Input2  dw 5 dup ('$')
answer  dw 10 dup ('$')
temp1   dw 10 dup ('$')

DTitle db "________________Calculator________________","$"
Dadd   db "A- Addition","$"
Dsub   db "S- Subtraction","$"
Dmul   db "M- Multiplication","$"
Ddiv   db "D- Division","$"
Dexit  db "E-Exit","$"

Dprompt db "Please Select An Operation:","$"

DispA  db "Addition","$"
DispS  db "Subtraction","$"
DispM  db "Multiplication","$"
DispD  db "Division","$"

Dprompt1 db "Enter 1st Number:","$"
Dprompt2 db "Enter 2nd Number:","$"
Danswer  db "Answer:","$"
Dnega db '-','$'
Drem db '+ remainder',"$"

DError db "Invalid Choice. Pleas Enter The Corresponding Letters.", "$"
Dloop db "Press Any Key To Continue. . .","$"

.code

Main:

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

Menu:    
;___________________________________________    
    mov ah, 06h     ;Clear Screen
    mov al, 00h
    mov bh, 0F1h
    mov cx, 0000h
    mov dx, 184Fh
    int 10h

    mov ah, 02h     ;Set Cursor
    mov bh, 00
    mov dh, 01h
    mov dl, 13h
    int 10h

    lea dx, DTitle   ;Display "Calculator"
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
;____________________________________________
   ;Display add
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dh, 03
    mov dl, 22h
    int 10h

    lea dx, Dadd
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

   ;Display sub 
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dh, 04
    mov dl, 22h
    int 10h

    lea dx, Dsub
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

   ;Dislay mul 
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dh, 05
    mov dl, 22h
    int 10h

    lea dx, Dmul
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

   ;Display div
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dh, 06
    mov dl, 22h
    int 10h

    lea dx, Ddiv
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

   ;Display Exit
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dh, 07
    mov dl, 22h
    int 10h

    lea dx, Dexit
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

   ;Display Prompt Message
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dh, 09
    mov dl, 1Ah
    int 10h

    lea dx, Dprompt
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

   ;Capture choice
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

   ;Stores choice to al 
    mov choice, al
;____________________________________________


;Input first number__________________________

    ;Set Cursor
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00
    mov dh, 11
    mov dl, 1Ah
    int 10h

    ;Display Dprompt1
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Dprompt1
    int 21h

    mov ax, 000h
    lea si, input1
    mov cx, 0000h

inputfirst:

    ;INPUT FIRST NUMBER
    mov ah, 1               ; input number
    int 21h           

    cmp al, 0dh             ; detect 'enter' press
    je exitfirst

    sub al, 30h             ; get decimal value

    mov byte ptr[si],al     ; point address of al to si pointer
    inc si                  ; proceed to next index

    jmp inputfirst

exitfirst:

    lea si, input1          ; point address of input1 to si
    mov bx, 0000h           ; clear bx
    mov bh, [si]            ; copy value of si to bh
    mov bl, [si+1]          ; copy value of the next index of si to bl

    mov ax, 10              ; initialize ax by 10
    mul bh                  ; multiply ax by bh

    add bl, al              ; add bl and al to complete decimal number
    mov bh, 00              ; clear bh

    mov input1, bx          ; save bx to input1    



;Input second number____________________________

    ;Set Cursor
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00
    mov dh, 13
    mov dl, 1Ah   
    int 10h

    ;DISPLAY MSG8
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Dprompt2
    int 21h

    mov ax, 0000h       ; clear ax
    mov bx, 0000h       ; clear bx
    lea si, Input2      ; point address of num2 to si
    mov cx, 0000h       ; clear cx

inputsecond: 

    ;INPUT SECOND NUMBER
    mov ah, 1           ; input character
    int 21h

    cmp al, 0dh         ; detect 'enter' press
    je exitsecond

    sub al, 30h         ; get decimal value

    mov byte ptr[si],al ; point address of al to pointer si
    inc si              ; proceed to next index

    jmp inputsecond

exitsecond:  

    lea si, Input2      ; point adress of num2 to si
    mov bx, 0000h       ; clear bx
    mov bh, [si]        ; copy value of si to bh
    mov bl, [si+1]      ; copy value of the next index of si to bl

    mov ax, 10          ; initialize ax by 10
    mul bh              ; multiply ax by bh

    add bl, al          ; add bl and al to complete decimal number
    mov bh, 00          ; clear bh

    mov Input2, bx      ; save bx to num2



;Testing choice__________________________________    
    cmp choice, 'A'    
    jne Test1
    call addition

Test1:    
    cmp choice, 'a'     
    jne Test2
    call addition

Test2:
    cmp choice, 'S'   
    jne Test3
    call subtraction

Test3:
    cmp choice, 's'   
    jne Test4
    call subtraction

Test4:    
    cmp choice, 'M'  
    jne Test5
    call multiplication

Test5:    
    cmp choice, 'm'   
    jne Test6
    call multiplication

Test6:        
    cmp choice, 'D'  
    jne Test7
    call division

Test7:        
    cmp choice, 'd'  
    jne Test8
    call division 

Test8:

    ;Set Cursor Position
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00
    mov dx, 1115h     
    int 10h

    ;Display Error Message
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, DError
    int 21h

    jmp Menu


stop:

    mov ax, 0000h     ; clear ax
    mov ax, answer    ; copy value of result to ax
    lea si, temp1      ; point address of temp to si
    call conversion

    ;Set Cursor
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00                 
    mov dx, 1115h     
    int 10h

    ;Displays answer
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Danswer
    int 21h

    ;displays temp1 
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, temp1
    int 21h      

exit:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h 

;_________________________________________
;Proceedures_____________________

;Conversion______________________________________
conversion proc near

        mov cx, 0000h     ; Reset cx
        mov bx, 10        ; set value for division

loop1:
        mov dx, 0         ; set first decimal value to 0
        div bx            ; Divide by 10
        add dl, '0'       ; Add by 30h to match ASCII
        push dx           ; copy value to stack
        inc cx            ; increment counter cx
        cmp ax, 9         ; compare value of ax to 9
        jg loop1          ; until ax value > 9, jump to loop1

        add al, '0'       ; Add by 30h to match ASCII
        mov [si], al      ; copy value to si

loop2:
        pop ax            ; get the last value from stack
        inc si            ; increment counter cx                    
        mov [si], al      ; copy value to si
        loop loop2        ; jump to loop2 
        ret

conversion endp
;_________________________________________________

;Operation Proceedures_____________________

;Addtion_____________
addition proc near

    mov ax, 0000h       ; clear ax
    mov bx, 0000h       ; clear bx
    mov ax, Input1      ; copy value of num1 to ax
    mov bx, Input2      ; copy value of num2 to bx
    add ax, bx        

    mov answer, ax      ; copy value of ax to result

    jmp stop

addition endp
;_____________________

;Subtraction__________
subtraction proc near

    mov ax, 0000h     ; clear ax
    mov bx, 0000h     ; clear bx
    mov ax, Input1      ; copy value of num1 to ax
    mov bx, Input2      ; copy value of num2 to bx

    cmp bx, ax        ; compare ax and bx
    jg secondgreat    ; if second input is greater, jump to secondgreat

    sub ax, bx        ; if first input is greater, proceed to subtraction
    mov answer, ax    ; copy value of ax to result

    jmp stop

secondgreat:

    mov ax, Input2      ; copy value of num2 to ax
    mov bx, Input1      ; copy value of num1 to bx
    sub ax, bx
    mov answer, ax    ; copy value of ax to result

    lea si, temp1      ; point address of temp to si
    call conversion

    ;SETTING CURSOR TO POSITION
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00
    mov dx, 1115h     ; Row 17, Column 21
    int 10h

    ;Display answer
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Danswer
    int 21h   

    ;display negative sign
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx, Dnega
    int 21h

    ;DISPLAY TEMP1
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset temp1
    int 21h

    jmp exit

subtraction endp
;_____________________

;Multiplication_______
multiplication proc near

    mov ax, 0000h     ; clear ax
    mov bx, 0000h     ; clear bx
    mov ax, Input1      ; copy value of num1 to ax
    mov bx, Input2      ; copy value of num2 to bx
    mul bx            ; multiply ax by bx

    mov answer, ax    ; copy value of ax to result

    jmp stop

multiplication endp
;_____________________

;Division_____________
division proc near

    mov ax, 0000h     ; clear ax
    mov bx, 0000h     ; clear bx
    mov ax, Input1      ; copy value of num1 to ax
    mov bx, Input2      ; copy value of num2 to bx
    div bl            ; divide ax by bl

    mov temp, al     ; copy value of al to temp1

    cmp ah, 00h       ; clear ah
    je noremainder

    mov ah, 00h       ; clear ah
    mov al, temp     ; copy value temp1 to al
    mov answer, ax    ; copy value of ax to result

    mov ax, 0000h     ; clear ax
    mov ax, answer    ; copy value of result to ax
    lea si, temp1      ; point address of temp to si
    call conversion

    ;SETTING CURSOR TO POSITION
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00
    mov dx, 1115h     ; Row 17, Column 15
    int 10h

    ;DISPLAY MSG9
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Danswer
    int 21h

    ;DISPLAY TEMP
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, temp1
    int 21h 

    ;DISPLAY MSG11  
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Drem
    int 21h

    jmp exit

noremainder:

    mov ah, 00h       ; clear ah
    mov al, temp     ; copy value of temp1 to al

    mov answer, ax    ; copy value of ax to result
    jmp stop

division endp
;_____________________

;_________________________________________________________

;End of program



End Main
```

Comment: If `ah` is zero, you jump to `noremainder` but if it's not zero you continue and set it to zero yourself. How do you expect it to work? Comment your code better, with intentions rather than obvious stuff - `clear ax` we can see that, but **why**? Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: `div bl` is a 8 bit division, the quotient is in `al` and the remainder in `ah`. If you clear `ah` you obviously lose the remainder.

Comment: Is my browser broken or is there no code here?  This is absolutely a useless question without the code.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer The original poster deleted the code from the question for some reason. I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have better shown us more from your code.  It's not clear what *conversion* does. We would understand better what you need if we were shown the actual text in *Danswer* and *Drem*.

Since you did a byte division `div bl` you obtained a quotient in AL and a remainder in AH.
You manage to show the quotient via *temp*, then *answer*, then *temp1 (conversion)*, and finally *int 21h*. You could take a shorter way here!

You need to take a comparable road to display the remainder. Make sure you push the AX register before you do the job on the quotient and pop AX just before doing the same job for the remainder.

From your comment: You didn't use **double word for temp1**.  You should have defined temp1 as `temp1 db 10 dup ('$')`